# Can I inheritance type for function parameter from object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use TypeScript in Angular. Earlier I set function parameters type with hardcoded, like this:

```
login(email: string) {}
```

Now I try use inheritance from other object and do it like this

```
import { User } from './user.model';

login(email: User['email']) {}
```

All works fine, but I can't find example like this in TypeScript cookbook and not sure, that I should set type like this.
Can I use above construction and what TypeScript guidelines think about it?

Comment: That sample doesn't make a whole lot of sense as is. Is there supposed to be an implicit `class {}` around it?

Comment: Sorry, I only try write simple example in this case.

Comment: Your usage is valid, you can read about it here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html, search for indexed access operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `T[field]` is a type query, not inheritance. Regardless of terminology it really depends on your use case. Type queries are more useful when you don't know the actual type of the object, or in mapped types:

```
class Test <T extends { key: any, value : any}>{
    getValue(key: T['key']) : T['value'] {
        return null;
    }
}

var t = new Test<{ key: number, value : string}>();
var foo = t.getValue(0) // only numbers are accepted, will foo be typed as string
```

This being said, you can use this syntax as you currently use it. If you change the type for `User[email]` all usages of the function will probably fail, which might be intended. If you don't believe the type of the field will change, I would stick with the actual type (`string` in this case) as it is more readable, but it is a matter of preference

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I only want store all information about User in one place in one model. Should I do like this? It's good practice get information about type from object? Or i should write it all the time?

Comment: @DenisSavenko I am not aware of this being bad practice, but I would not personally use it, I feel it makes things harder to read and it seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you. I think, I forgot about KISS:)